# Calling a C# function when input is changed in cshtml

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

I'm trying to call a C# function `Update()` from the `cshtml`.

It should be called whenever the input is changed.

This is `Run.cshtml`:

```
@page
@model RunModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Run";
}
<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

<p>
    <br />
    Solve @ViewData["Problem"]
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="YourInput" autocomplete="off" autofocus onchange="Update()">
    <br />
    Your input: @ViewData["YourInput"]
</p>
```

This is `Run.cshtml.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Mastery.Pages
{
    public class RunModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ILogger<RunModel> _logger;

        public RunModel(ILogger<RunModel> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            var node = Run.ChooseNode();
            var problem = node.GenerateProblem();
            ViewData["Problem"] = problem.Text;
        }

        public void Update()
        {
            ViewData["YourInput"] = Request.Query["YourInput"];
        }
    }
}
```

How can you call the `Update()` function when the cshtml input is changed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax to pass data to handler,and handler return data to ajax,then replace html with the data.Here is a working demo：

```
<p>
    <br />
    Solve @ViewData["Problem"]
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="YourInput" autocomplete="off" autofocus onchange="Update(this)">
    <div id="div1">Your input: @ViewData["YourInput"]</div>
</p>
@section scripts
{
    <script>
        function Update(t) {
            var url = '?handler=Update&&YourInput=' + $(t).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: '?handler=Update&&YourInput='+$(t).val(),
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#div1").html("Your input:" +data);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("fail");
                }
            })
        }
    </script>

}
```

handler:

```
public IActionResult OnGetUpdate()
        {
            ViewData["YourInput"] = Request.Query["YourInput"];
            return Content(ViewData["YourInput"].ToString());
        }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'm currently getting some weird behavior with this though. The handler (which I put in the cshtml.cs) isn't getting called, and "Your input:" has a copy of the run page after it instead of the input. Thanks again.

Comment: Can you share your current code,is your handler name right?

Comment: My code is exactly as you put it here, I copy-pasted again to be sure. I put break points on the handler and the constructor in Run.cshtml to check if they're getting called, and they aren't.

Comment: Can you check  the request in Network when you click the button,and check if it has errors in Console?

Comment: There's nothing in the output window. I'm not sure how to check the network.

Comment: Try to click `F12`.